Wavelength and frequency of the peak of the black body radiation
Why does the product of the peak wavelength and the peak frequency of Planck's black body radiation not equal to the speed of light?
$$λ_{\mathrm{max}}=\frac{hc}{4.97\mathrm{kT}},$$ while $$ν_{\mathrm{max}}=\frac{2.82\mathrm{kT}}{h}.$$

Does this answer your question? The strange thing about the maximum in Planck's law

what about number of photons per Hz per str per m2?
